# Unable to compare dates in Spark SQL query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Using PySpark and JDBC driver for MySQL I am not able to query for columns of type date. java.lang.ClassCastException is thrown.

```py
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.load(source="jdbc", url=url, dbtable="reports")
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df, "reports")
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
#  |-- day: date (nullable = false)
query = sqlContext.sql("select * from reports where day > '2015-05-01'")
query.collect() # ... most recent failure: ... java.lang.ClassCastException
```

Changing day column's type to timestamp solves the problem, but I have to keep the original schema.

Answer (score 13):

Looking at the [relevant unit tests](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLQuerySuite.scala) in the Spark source, it looks like you need an explicit cast:

```
select * from reports where day > cast('2015-05-01' as date)
```

There's no sign of it in the Spark SQL documentation, but it seems to have been available in Transact-SQL and Hive for some time.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException still occures. I need to investigate it further but it might be a bug. `select day, cast('2004-04-14' as date) as day2 from reports` returns rows with fields of the same type: `Row(day=datetime.date(2015, 4, 22), day2=datetime.date(2004, 4, 14)`, but it fails when compared.

Comment: What version of Spark are you using? I think it may be a bug in Spark's JDBC support -- I'm not set up to easily test it, at least against MySQL. It works for me in raw Spark SQL in Spark 1.3.1 as you can see [here](https://github.com/spirom/LearningSpark/blob/master/src/main/scala/sql/DateTime.scala). (You're also making me realize the cast doesn't seem to be necessary.) You may want to check out [SPARK-6967](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6967) and [SPARK-7364](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7364) will likely be a problem for you too.

Comment: BTW, notice that both issues are marked "resolved", but only the first one is targeted for the 1.3.2 release. For the other you'll apparently have to wait for 1.4.0 unless you want to add to the ticket and argue for 1.3.2 as well. I haven't done this so don't know how likely you are to succeed. It may be too late in the 1.3.2 cycle.